# Netlogo different global values from turtles

Tags: netlogo

I don't understand why something appened in my netlogo code, but finally I found that a global variables change values from turtles to turtles, is this possible?
I noticed this because I have 2 print value in my code like this:

```
breed [players player]
breed [balls ball]

globals [
  TURNS;
  TEAM-OWNER
]
to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  set TURNS 0
  setup-players
  setup-ball
end

to setup-ball
  create-balls 1 [
    setxy 0 0
    set color orange
    set shape "bug"
    set size 2.5
  ]
end 

to setup-players
  create-players 5 [
    setxy 0 0
    set color white
    set shape "bug"
    set size 2.5
  ]
end 

to go 
  set TURNS TURNS + 1
  print word "this is the turns " TURNS
  print ( word " values " TEAM-OWNER)
  if ticks >= 1000 [ stop ]

    ask players [
    print ( word " values " TEAM-OWNER)
    fd 2 
    set TEAM-OWNER "red"
  ]

  ask balls [
    fd 2
    set TEAM-OWNER "black"
  ]

end
```

Is this possible? Global values doesn't change it values in all turtles?
This is the print that I got:

```
this is the turns  1
values 0
values 0
values red
values red
values red
values red
this is the turns 2
values black
values black
values red
values red
values red
values red
```

It has not be like black 1 times ? and red the other times? And Why I get 2 blacks?

Comment: It should not happen - globals are the same for everyone.  You'll need to add more code in for people to spot the problem - the `globals` declaration, any `turtles-own` or `breeds-own` declarations, and any code the players are running before or after they `print` the `MY-GLOBAL-VALUE` since they could be changing it (most likely cause).

Comment: @Jasper I have put all the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A global variable is global - there is only ONE copy of it and all turtles retrieve and modify the same copy.

Look at this piece of your code:

```
ask players [
  print ( word " values " TEAM-OWNER)
  fd 2 
  set TEAM-OWNER "red"
]

ask balls [
  fd 2
  set TEAM-OWNER "black"
]
```

First, every one of your players moves forward two distance units, then sets the value of TEAM-OWNER to "red". If you have 10 players, then the global variable TEAM-OWNER is being set to red 10 times. Then every one of your balls moves forward two distance units and sets the variable TEAM-OWNER to "black". As long as you have one (or more) balls, then the global variable will be overwritten.

A global variable is used for something that is the same for every turtle in your model.

Comment: ok but why in the first turn, the 0 values is printed 2 times? and the same appened with the black values?

Comment: Because at the beginning of turn 2, the first thing you do is print the TEAM-VALUE (that's the first "black"), then the first player prints it again (the second one) before changing it to "red" for the other 4 players to print.